# Access COMDLG32.dll Reference Gone

Tags: ms-access, dialog

To make a specific application work on another user's machine, we removed a reference for Microsoft Common Dialog Control 6.0 (SP3), or "COMDLG32.dll", from the application. We thought this would be appropriate because the application appeared to compile just fine without it.

Unfortunately, this was a trick. The reference appears to be required for different control boxes used throughout the app. Now that it's been removed, I can't seem to locate it in the References selection box in Access's VBA editor.

It used to be referenced by name (Microsoft Common Dialog Control 6.0) in the list of Available References to add to the application. Now, I'm only able to find the reference if I browse to the list of common references. "COMDLG32.dll" is an option. However, if I select the file, I'm told that I'm unable to use the reference.

Help?

Comment: Do access describe why you are unable to use it ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It simply says "Can't add a reference to the specified file." As usual, Microsoft's "Help" button is of no help, as the information is far too general. A Google search on the error failed to produce any useful information, as well.

Comment: are os and/or office 64bit ? what is the path to COMDLG32.dll ?

Comment: Path is: "C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll". I'm using a Win8 64Bit machine.

Comment: do you have comdlg32.dll in c:\windows\wow64\ ? Is MSoffice 32 bit?

Comment: comdlg32.dll exists in \WOW64, but displays the same error message as its 32-bit counterpart. MS Office appears to be 64-bit. Version 2013.

Comment: 64bit office can't use 32bit ActiveX

Comment: When you add a common dialog com object to a form, it will add it's reference (comdlg32) to the VBA project. Presumably you imported this project from a 32bit version and it didn't covert correctly: you need to replace comdlg32.ocx controls with comdlg64.ocx controls.